# addEventListener Throwing an Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get my head around the addEventListener() function and have set up some code on a localhost install, but when I run the code I'm getting an error message:  Uncaught TypeError: section2.addEventListener is not a function.

The code is below, basically when section2 loads (which will hold video content), I want section1 (which contains a preloader) to disappear. For ease of code I'm using jQuery for the variables.  I've used console.log to test that the variables are showing on the live site and they are.

```
var section1 = $("#section1"),
    section2 = $("#section2");


section2.addEventListener("load", function(){

     section1.style.display="none";

})
```

I can't seem to work out why it isn't working?

Comment: `addEventListener` is a function on `EventTarget` objects, like `HTMLElement`s, _not_ jQuery objects.

Comment: See jQuery's [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) : "Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements."

Comment: Thanks. That has stopped the error in the console, section1 isn't actually disappearing though when section 2 has loaded?

Comment: @EmilyChewy separate problem. load only works on certain types of elements, like images and iframes. you know, things that load things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Xufox said directly under your post, its not an object, jQuery selects by $('...').

Option a) pure Javascript:

```
var section1 = document.getElementById('section1'),
    section2 = document.getElementById('section2');
```

Option b) Jquery:

```
section2.on("load", function(){
     section1.hide();
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That has stopped the error in the console, section1 isn't actually disappearing though when section 2 has loaded?

Comment: @EmilyChewy separate problem. `load` only works on certain types of elements, like images and iframes. you know, things that load things.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I'm new to JS.  I'll have to go and research what elements it works on.  That has put me at a bit of a loss as to how to do a JS pre-loader then.  I guess I'll need to add it to the <head> and run the load on the body or something?

Comment: @EmilyChewy please close the question by adding the checkmark and ask your questions in a new post. But I think, with a little patience you will find out by yourself ;)

Comment: how do I add a checkmark, I can't see where to do that?

Comment: It should be on the left, under the "arrow up", 2, "arrow down".